# How do I get these 2 cases to pass in my code?

Tags: python, regex

I need to create code where when I run it, it passes in the console for each test.

My last 2 tests need to test if password/secret are used, except I'm having difficulties creating code for this step.

I tried adding the following to the top in an effort to make things work:

```
    if not re.search(r'(password)', candidate):
        error_messages.append('Password may not contain the word "password" in any case.')

    if not re.search(r'(secret)', candidate):
        error_messages.append('Password may not contain the word "secret" in any case.')
```

I also tried using square brackets [] instead of parentheses above around secret and password but this didn't seem to do anything. Any tips?

```
import re


def validate_password(candidate):
    error_messages = []  # returning empty list indicates password is valid

    if len(candidate) < 6:
        error_messages.append('Password must be at least 6 characters long.')

    if not re.search(r'[A-Z]', candidate):
        error_messages.append('Password must include at least one upper-case letter (A-Z).')

    if not re.search(r'[a-z]', candidate):
        error_messages.append('Password must include at least one lower-case letter (a-z).')

    if not re.search(r'[!@#$%^&*]', candidate):
        error_messages.append('Password must include at least one special character (!@#$%^&*).')

    return error_messages


def main():
    print('Unit testing output...')

    print('\nTest case 1: password too short')
    input_password = 'Ab#45'
    expected_result = ['Password must be at least 6 characters long.']
    actual_result = validate_password(input_password)
    if actual_result == expected_result:
        print('passed')
    else:
        print('failed')

    print('\nTest case 2: password meets all criteria')
    input_password = 'Bc&456'
    expected_result = []
    actual_result = validate_password(input_password)
    if actual_result == expected_result:
        print('passed')
    else:
        print('failed')

    print('\nTest case 3: password missing upper case letter')
    input_password = 'ac&456'
    expected_result = ['Password must include at least one upper-case letter (A-Z).']
    actual_result = validate_password(input_password)
    if actual_result == expected_result:
        print('passed')
    else:
        print('failed')

    print('\nTest case 4: password missing lower-case letter')
    input_password = 'A*3456'
    expected_result = ['Password must include at least one lower-case letter (a-z).']
    actual_result = validate_password(input_password)
    if actual_result == expected_result:
        print('passed')
    else:
        print('failed')

    print('\nTest case 5: password missing special character')
    input_password = 'Ab3456'
    expected_result = ['Password must include at least one special character (!@#$%^&*).']
    actual_result = validate_password(input_password)
    if actual_result == expected_result:
        print('passed')
    else:
        print('failed')

    print('\nTest case 6: password missing multiple of the criteria')
    input_password = '12345'
    msg_1 = 'Password must be at least 6 characters long.'
    msg_2 = 'Password must include at least one upper-case letter (A-Z).'
    msg_3 = 'Password must include at least one lower-case letter (a-z).'
    msg_4 = 'Password must include at least one special character (!@#$%^&*).'
    expected_result = [msg_1, msg_2, msg_3, msg_4]
    actual_result = validate_password(input_password)
    if actual_result == expected_result:
        print('passed')
    else:
        print('failed')

    print('\nTest case 7: password contains word password')
    input_password = 'password'
    expected_result = ['Password may not contain the word "password" in any case.']
    actual_result = validate_password(input_password)
    if actual_result == expected_result:
        print('passed')
    else:
        print('failed')

    print('\nTest case 8: password contains word secret')
    input_password = 'secret'
    expected_result = ['Password may not contain the word "secret" in any case.']
    actual_result = validate_password(input_password)
    if actual_result == expected_result:
        print('passed')
    else:
        print('failed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks!

P.S.: If anyone has good regex resources please let me know, this part is rather confusing for me.

Comment: You are adding the message if the password does **not** contain 'password' or 'secret', remove the `not` of your condition. Also, you should do a case insensitive search (`re.I`) according to your messages.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: "... and it didn't work" - sorry, but that isn't accurate enough. Please provide the exact code you ran and its output vs expected output.

Comment: Your expected results are wrong. 'password' should trigger two more messages, as it doesn't contain any uppercase nor any special character. Please correct them - and note that the order of the messages probably shouldn't matter.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille is right
 if re.search(r'(password)', candidate, re.I): should work

Comment: Yes, it does. As a side note, an easy way to see what is happening would be to print the actual messages returned.